# Array Index Out of Bounds: Matrix (Dot Product)

Tags: arrays, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

Use 2-dimensional arrays to represent matrices.
Compute the product of the matrices and store the data in a new 2-dimensinal array.
Print the product of Matrix A Row 2 and Matrix B Column 1.
You want to multiply A and B, to find the product matrix C. For ease, assume that (for now) you only want to compute the value at row 2, column 1, in the product matrix C.
But, to compute the value in row2, column 1, of the matrix C, you will need to compute the “dot product” of A’s entire row 2, and B’s entire column 1:

My program is telling me that my Array Index is out of bounds with an exception at 4, but I'm not sure how to solve it

```
public class lab
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int[][] A = { {10,55,4,89,39} , {45,9,49,98,23} , {4,8,90,23,9} 
{8,32,80,2,31} };

      int[][] B = { {10,55,4,89,39} , {45,9,49,98,23} , {4,8,90,23,9} , {8,32,80,2,31} };

      int[][] C = new int[A.length][B[0].length];

      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
      {
         sum = sum + A[2][i]*B[i][1];
      }

      C[2][1] = sum;

      System.out.println(sum);

   } // end main
} // end class
```

The output should be:

1616

Comment: in which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: at: sum = sum + A[2][i] * B[i][1]

Comment: B has only 4 elements. but you are trying to access  5 elements. change the loop

Comment: post the equation you need to calculate like , 45*16 + 35*2 + etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Your both the Array A & B have 4 elements, you are running the loop through 5. You need to change the for loop like below.

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Array B you can`t get element of B[4][4].
Maximum will be B[3][4].
array indexes starts from 0. so you have elements. 0,1,2,3.
when counter hits 4, you try to get the element B[4]  and the index doesn`t exist.
That`s why you are getting the error.
Check the attached image too. [image]
check below image

Comment: Also check http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult3.htm
I think this matrix operation is undefined